# Opencart 2: Events not triggered

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-events

I'm using opencart version 2.1.0.1 and trying to use the new script notification system.
Please note that I have simply installed the original version. Nothing extra added or modified.

Following the tutorial found here: http://isenselabs.com/posts/opencart2-event-system-tutorial
I managed to create a new module and install it successfully.
I can confirm from the database that it has registered the events that I want to trigger.

To give you a better picture I have created these files:

- admin/controller/module/testo.php
- admin/view/template/module.testo.tpl
- admin/language/english/module/testo.php
- catalog/controller/module/testo.php

Now although the admin events are triggered with no problem the Catalog (fronted) Order Events never fire.

On admin/controller/module/testo.php function install I have the following call:

```
$this->model_extension_event->addEvent('testo', 'post.order.add', 'module/testo/on_order_add');
```

And according to the tutorial the function to fire should be in catalog/controller/model/testo.php

```
public function on_order_add($order_id) { .... }
```

The function simply writes the order_id to a text file, nothing tricky there.

So when I complete an order the function never runs.
I have tried most Order Notification Hooks with no luck.

Am I missing something?
Is there something I'm not understanding?
Please help since there is absolutely no documentation and I'm on a dead end (for the time)

Comment: Have you tried by changing event name?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Note that triggers in dot notation are no longer supported in newer versions of OpenCart; this was changed to use route notation. See https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Events-(script-notifications)-2.2.x.x

Answer (score 1):

You are calling it incorrectly, your catalog file path must be

```
catalog/controller/module/testo.php
```

not

```
catalog/controller/model/testo.php
```

because your trigger is

```
$this->model_extension_event->addEvent('testo', 'post.order.add', 'module/testo/on_order_add');
```

it's meaning -> Opencart will search catalog/controller/module/testo.php file and will call it's on_order_add() function when 'post.order.add' trigger will execute (because trigger in catalog side it will use catalog/* or else it will use admin/*), 'testo' is just name part noting important.

In your case it's searching correctly but you don't have any file on this path because you added file to

```
catalog/controller/model/testo.php
```

so change your folder structure -> model to module or change your trigger from module to model.

Comment: You are right but I just noted that model was a typo .. I have the file inside /module folder. So the problem is something else! I will edit the post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure writing to text file is working?

because i also tried to get post.order.add event on my Opencart 2.0.3.1, and its working fine.

try writing to log file

```
<?php

class ControllerModuleTesto extends Controller
{
    public function on_order_add($order_id)  
    {
        $this->log->write("Order Id " . $order_id . " was created."); 
    }
}
?>
```

and check logs at backend->Tools->Error Logs